# What is the replacement for `?` and `.` in PHP CURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have a PHP CURL query which is of the form 
curl -u emailid:password -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "test?@test.comTestTest Details" -X POST http://url/xxx.xml

The query works fine for all email addresses except those that have `&`, `?` or `.` where I get an xml query format error.

When I replace `&` with `&amp;` the `&` problem is solved.
However, I am unable to find a replacement for `?` and `.` 
I tried the replacements  `&#x3f;` for `?` and `&#x2e` for `.` but I still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

the -d parameter is expected to be [url encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (not xml-encoded).  So `?` will be `%3f`; and `.` will be `%2e`.

The fact that `&amp;` actually worked is somewhat surprising -- it really should be encoded as `%26` instead.